# How to set the webroot in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, webroot

I'm learning Magento 2 and can see that Magento has two `index.php` files. One is in the root folder and another one is in Pub folder. While reading many of the posts regarding webroot of Magento, I can see that we have to set the webroot to Pub folder for security.

Currently, I have installed the Magento in Xampp.

Can anyone please tell me how to set the webroot to Pub in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

To set webroot to pub you will have to tell Magento where the pub folder actually is with something like this

```
#File: pub/index.php
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Mage::PARAM_APP_URIS][Mage_Core_Model_Dir::PUB] = '';
$entryPoint = new Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http(new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Primary(BP, $params));
```

You can also refer to https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-the-pub-folder/. But be ready to face some problems. You can find some of the problems you will face here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15092

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by updating your virtual host file, you need to change DocumentRoot `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2ce/pub`:

Example code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2ce/pub

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                    AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

For more information refer magento 2 devdocs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html